# javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS013323: Invalid User

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly, jaas

On my way to migrate from JBoss 7 to WildFly, I encountered another problem. When calling an rest service which is protected by `@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")` I get the following error:

```
13:46:44,359 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component TestFacade for method public java.lang.String net.dice.facade.TestFacade.generateTestdata(): javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: JBAS013323: Invalid User
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:66) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:46) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:92) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:448)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:326)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at net.dice.facade.TestFacade$$$view3.generateTestdata(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:280) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:234) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:221) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.6.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at net.dice.filter.DiceFilter.doFilter(DiceFilter.java:48) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:168) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:687) [undertow-core-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```

My Bean:

```
@Stateless
@Path("testdata")
@RolesAllowed({ "ADMIN" })
public class TestFacade extends GenericService {
```

web.xml:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>REST services</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>dice</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
</security-role>
```

My standalone.xml:

```xml
<security-domain name="dice">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/jdbc/dice"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select passwordHash from player where lower(playertag)= lower(?)"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role, 'Roles' from playerrole pr join player p on (pr.player_id = p.id) where lower(p.playertag)= lower(?)"/>
            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

The query for the roles returns: ADMIN, Roles (like mentioned in the spec)

The strange thing is when I remove the `@RolesAllowed` and check the Roles of the User with `isCallerInRole(String)` he has the admin role.

```
System.out.println(ctx.isCallerInRole("ADMIN")); // true
System.out.println(ctx.isCallerInRole("USER")); // false (is ok. he is just admin)
System.out.println(ctx.isCallerInRole("USERdsd")); // false (nonexisting role)
```

Can anyone spot my mistake? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solved it. The default security domain for the ejb subsystem was set to other per default. I just removed  in  (standalone.xml) and it worked!

Comment: To fix in JBoss EAP 6.2, I set the default-security-domain entry in the EJB subsystem (in standalone.xml) to the name of my security domain.

Comment: Same in case of Wildfly 8.2.0 Final

Comment: The default security domain tag itself caused the error, even when pointing to the right security domain. Removing it from `standalone.xml` fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

As @mkuff described, removing the default security domain from the EJB subsystem helps. Here's how to do that with JBoss CLI:

```
$WILDFLY_LOCATION/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c \
  --command='/subsystem=ejb3:undefine-attribute(name=default-security-domain)'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also a problem with JBoss 7.2.  A call to a method in a SLSB annotated with @PermitAll worked fine in JBoss 7.1.1 and 7.1.3 but got permission denied in jboss 7.2.0.Final.

After reading this I changed the default security domain to our applications domain and it worked. What I don't really see is why @PermitAll methods need to do any authenticating at all.